# $(window).scrollTop(value) doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input with a map below:
**input with map**

[image]

The trouble is when I focus the input on mobile phone, the keyboard pops up and the input goes out of view.
I tried to scroll the page to position in which the input is in view after the keyboard pops up, but in Chrome on Android **$(window).scrollTop(value)** doesn't work. I use it like this:

```js
$shopListSearch.on('focus', function() {

  let
    $this = $(this),
    thisHeight = $this.innerHeight(),
    value = thisOffsetTop - thisHeight - $header.innerHeight();
  
  //timeout to wait while keyboard pops up
  setTimeout(function() {
    $window.scrollTop(value);
  }, 2000);

});
```

This works in Chrome emulator of mobile device, but it doesn't work on real Android mobile phone. What can I do to make it work on phone?

Comment: `value` variable should be `$this.offset().top - $header.innerHeight();`. If you subtract  `thisHeight`, it goes up out of window view. Try to use `var` instead of `let` for good practice. Because `let`(ES6) is compatible with modern browsers. When `var` is compatible with almost all browsers.

Comment: The problem is $window.scrollTop(value) does nothing at all on Android mobile phone, not the scroll value is incorrect.
And I use transpiler, so "let" is auto transpiled to var.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the block with height calculated by script on the top of the page. So when the kb pops up on android, viewbox size changes and the top block height changes. The result is input y-pos decreases, when the scroll position is the same. The solution is simple - check if the input is in focus when calculating top block height.